# Does javapns support broadcast push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I googled javapns and nothing show that it support broadcast diffusion.
It there a trick to make it support broadcast?

I am using this code right now, and adding all my available tokens in the call:

```
    try {

        PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();

        payload.addAlert("Hello World");
        payload.addBadge(1);
        payload.addSound("default");
        payload.addCustomDictionary("id", "1");

        System.out.println(payload.toString());
        List<PushedNotification> NOTIFICATIONS = Push
                .payload(payload, "D:\\keystore1.p12", "123456", true,
                        "-------------");           
         for (PushedNotification NOTIFICATION : NOTIFICATIONS) {
            if (NOTIFICATION.isSuccessful()) {
                /* APPLE ACCEPTED THE NOTIFICATION AND SHOULD DELIVER IT */
                System.out
                        .println("PUSH NOTIFICATION SENT SUCCESSFULLY TO: "
                                + NOTIFICATION.getDevice().getToken());
                /* STILL NEED TO QUERY THE FEEDBACK SERVICE REGULARLY */
            } else {
                String INVALIDTOKEN = NOTIFICATION.getDevice().getToken();
                /* ADD CODE HERE TO REMOVE INVALIDTOKEN FROM YOUR DATABASE */

                /* FIND OUT MORE ABOUT WHAT THE PROBLEM WAS */
                Exception THEPROBLEM = NOTIFICATION.getException();
                THEPROBLEM.printStackTrace();

                /*
                 * IF THE PROBLEM WAS AN ERROR-RESPONSE PACKET RETURNED BY
                 * APPLE, GET IT
                 */
                ResponsePacket THEERRORRESPONSE = NOTIFICATION
                        .getResponse();
                if (THEERRORRESPONSE != null) {
                    System.out.println(THEERRORRESPONSE.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Broadcast notification does not exists. IOS Push notification service has only one implementation and it takes token list of clients.

So you have to get tokens of your client, then use your script.